# C# WPF - Multiple MainWindow.xaml on a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

My `MainWindow.xaml` is a `live graph` which I have created. I intend to create multiple (four) instances of the similar graph and placed it nicely in a 2 x 2 grid. I want to duplicate four `MainWindow.xaml` and pin it nicely on a 2 x 2 grid. An example is below :

#### Example

[image: Multiple MainWindow.xaml]

I know that it is possible by creating multiple charts in the back-end coding but however due to some API restriction , i am not able to do this.

Comment: Do you want 4 separate windows or a 2x2 grid in xaml?

Comment: You could make a `UserControl` (with the live-chart) and then place it 4 times on your `MainWindow.xaml`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve and what is the problem. You said you are new and you also mentioned API restrictions. What restrictions? "Multiple MainWindow.xaml" sounds like single user control used 4 times in `MainWindow.xaml`, but I am unsure.

Comment: I think any usercontrols  might be overthinking this. Just 4 grids in mainwindow looks like it'd work.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all for the reply. Yes i have figured out using the Multiple document interface to create multiple user controls in a main window. But another issue will be the data binding of my user control variables as currently i am using the INotifyPropertyChanged. E.g. running multiple duplicate user control as an unique instance.